# Simple Rounded Corner Shape ListView

Tags: android, listview

I am trying to make simple Rounded Corner Shape ListView

Using below xmls;

**row_layout.xml:-**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**activity_main.xml:-**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

   <ListView 
       android:id="@+id/listView"   
       android:background="@drawable/layout_border"           
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: You just put padding to your textview inside single item xml file.

Comment: @Hardy hi i want exact same look as required listview image

Comment: Yes.. Did you checked after applying paddding ?

Comment: You also need to change border color in layout_border.xml

Comment: @Hardy yeah i followed and now getting ListItem view like i wanted but what to do if i want List corners in black not in grey like i am getting

Comment: @Sonali change border color also. in your file.

Comment: @Sonali welcome happy codding :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39260/discussion-between-hardy-and-sonali)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Add padding to TextView of list row. And seems the required output doesn't have bold text so remove `android:textStyle="bold"` from `TextView`***

So you should update `row_layout`

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/name" android:padding="10dip"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

OR

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="5dip"
    android:paddingRight="5dip"
    android:paddingTop="10dip"
    android:paddingBottom="10dip"/>
```

---

Few other changes

into `layout_border.xml` : -

```
<stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="#FF000000" /> // idip and color black
```

into `activity_main.xml` :-

```
<ListView 
       android:id="@+id/listView"   
       android:background="@drawable/layout_border"           
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:dividerHeight="1dip"
       android:divider="#FF000000"
       />
```

Comment: @Sonali Most welcome. Thank god... I was thinking that you are not viewing this answer...

Comment: it's not possible, because you are trying to help me without any condition or situation, thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

Put padding inside your Textview like...

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"   
        android:padding="10dip"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

As you mentioned you need to change your border color in your `layout_border.xml`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
    <stroke android:width="3dip" android:color="#B1BCBE" />   Change color here
                                                ^^^^^^^^^
    <corners android:radius="10dip"/>
    <padding android:left="0dip" android:top="0dip" android:right="0dip" android:bottom="0dip" />
</shape>
```

Comment: sorry i want to tick on accepted, but as you know Pankaj has written as answer, but i ticked on useful i hope you would not mind it

Comment: Glad to help you once again :)

Comment: so why should not try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19087677/add-event-to-custom-calendar-using-sqlite, as you know you given me the link to create custom calendar but storing events using SQLite in Calendar still pending

Answer (score 0):

1. set padding for textview in row_layout:

   ```
       <TextView
           android:id="@+id/name"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:textStyle="bold" />

   </RelativeLayout>
   ```
2. set divide for listview in activity_main:

   ```
      <ListView       
          android:id="@+id/listView"   
          android:background="@drawable/layout_border"           
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:divider="#999999"
          android:dividerHeight="3dp"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>

   </RelativeLayout>
   ```